# Get path of a file in resourcer even when its in a jar

Tags: java

I have a Json file in resources and I am using this code to use the information that it have:

```
JsonClass myWantedInfo;
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.json");
Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(res.toURI()));
gson.toJson(myWantedInfo, writer);
writer.close();
```

When i use my IDE (Eclipse - Spring Tool Suite 4), this code works. But when i build a JAR of my proyect its throw me an error (FileNotFoundException).
I have search a little and I found that the reason is that in my code the source is in src/main/resources but in the jar is at the root directory. But I don't find how can I resolve this problem.

To build the jar, I go to the path where my pom is and, using cmd, I use: mvn clean install.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your description reads as if you're using an IDE to run your code ("my local") and this should "translate" `src/main/resources` to the root of the classpath. When building the jar any file in that location should be part of the jar and in its root. Is that the case? If not you might want to share more details on your build, how you run your "local" code etc. (btw, you might want to do so in any case).

Comment: Resource are **read-only**. You cannot write to a resource when the application is deployed as a jar/war/... file.

Comment: There is no such thing as “path of a file” for a resource in a .jar, because that resource is not an actual file.  A .jar file is an actual file;  each .jar entry is a part of that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error with reading properties file. After a bit of research I added this piece of code to pom:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

And this is how I read from the file:

```
/**
 * loads default config from internal source
 *
 * @return true/false upon success/failure of loading config
 */
private static boolean loadDefault() {

    if (null != properties) return false;

    try (InputStream resourceStream = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(resourceStream);
        return true;

    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException exception) {

        String detail = ExceptionHandler.format(exception, "Could not load default config");
        log.error(detail);

        properties = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources are meant to used an inputs to a system - whereas here you are attempting to write to one. It seems extremely error prone (not to mention poor form) to be attempting to write into a runtime jar. So your `FileNotFoundException` is actually as expected (there is no resource named `file.json`). You should be creating your output object (`OutputStream` or `Writer`) from a `File` or `Path` (i.e. either explicitly giving a directory in which the file should created, using the current working directory or using the java.io methods for creating a temporary file it the runtime's `java.io.tmpdir` directory).

Either that or your code is "turned the wrong way" and you have confused reading and writing.